# Storing event listeners in functions and calling that function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an event listener within a function and every time the function is called, the event listener keeps getting attached and the code within the event listener gets triggered multiple times depending on the number of times that function has been called. How do I go around this?

```
function myFunction() {
    $("#element").on("click", function() {
        alert("test");
    }
}

$("body").on("click", function() {
    myFunction();
});
```

every time myFunction() is called an additional click event listener is added, so If I click the body 5 times, then click "#element". the alert message will be run 5 times despite only clicking on it once.

Comment: Take the event attachment code out of that function?

Comment: Add the code to your question.

Comment: *"How do I go around this?"* Don't attach the event handler inside the function.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by this code? What output do you expect? That is not the right way to bind events.

Comment: Why are you doing that?

Comment: The actual code is more complex, but the reason is because I need to check that a div has a certain class, and then I need to add the event listener if it does have the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you must do that, use `off` then `on` to ensure it is not connected more than once. To ensure you do not remove anyone else's handlers, add a custom namespace to the event (e.g. `.mycustom` below):

```
function myFunction() {
    $("#element").off('click.mycustom').on("click.mycustom", function() {
        alert("test");
    }
}
```

Custom namespaces have no effect on the events, but ensure you can access just that specific version of `click` later with `off`.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, [`addEventListener`](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#dom-eventtarget-addeventlistener) doesn't append the event listener to the list of event listeners if there already is an event listener in that list with the same type, callback, and capture.

However, the problem is that you recreate a new (different) callback at each call of `myFunction`. To avoid that, you should store the callback in a variable outside `myFunction`.

But even if you do that, jQuery will still call the callback multiple times. So just use vanilla-js:

```js
function callback() {
  alert("test");
}
function myFunction() {
  document.querySelector("#element").addEventListener("click", callback);
}
```

```js
function callback() {
  alert("test");
}
function myFunction() {
  document.querySelector("#element").addEventListener("click", callback);
}
$("body").on("click", myFunction);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Some content — click me first.
<div id="element">Element — then click me</div>
```